# Is there a convenient way to search and view the implementation source code for a specific JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript, c, browser, v8

Imagine I want to check how `Object.keys()` is implemented in V8. Or `String.prototype.indexOf()`. Or any other JS method.

Is there a convenient online resource to view the portion of source code that implements a specific function, without having to "grep" through the entire engine codebase?

I wish they had this feature directly included in the MDN docs!

Comment: It isn't that clear cut, array.pop for example has multiple implementations, [one in JavaScript](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/master/src/array.js#L423-L441), [one in C++](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/master/src/builtins.cc#L407-L438) and [one in Hydrogen](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/master/src/hydrogen.cc#L8315-L8372) (a high level IR language). And if you can even understand the implementations you probably know the codebase well enough to make any online resource maintaining a waste of time..

Comment: Hi Esailija, if you read my original question again, you'll see I was talking about a specific language (JavaScript) and a specific implementation (v8, or others).

Imho it's a pity there's no online resource so far that conveniently allows to quickly look up the implementation details of a specific method, isolated from the rest.

Comment: Read my comment again  - I was only taking about V8 indeed... the point is that you have the idea that a method is simply implemented somewhere  as a single standalone function and that's it but it's wrong

Comment: @Esailija, ooops, I see  :)  Thanks for the clarification! It seems to be more complicated than I hoped. How comes methods are implemented in different places?

Comment: Because array.pop (and any javascript method in general) can have tons of edge cases but in normal usage it would be incredibly inefficient to handle those.

Answer (score 1):

in nodejs this works for methods written in js (but *not* for native code):

```
console.log( Object.keys.toString() )
```

Native code is written in C++, I look those up in the sources.

Comment: Hi Andras, when you say "I look those up in the sources" do you mean [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master/src/)? Cheers

Comment: not directly in v8, since I use nodejs I look in https://github.com/joyent/node, but node ships with a full copy of v8 as a dependency.  I have a local checkout so I can search from the command line.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But still, going back to the original question, does this mean that there's no online resource so far that allows to quickly look up the implementation details of a specific method, isolated from the rest (at least for one engine, let's say v8)?